# MSMTP: 550 MIME message is missing 'From' header, even if address is defined in msmtp config properly

Tags: nginx, bitrix, msmtp

current msmtp configuration

```
account default
logfile /home/bitrix/msmtp_default.log
host smtp.sendgrid.net
port 587
from xyz@domain.com
aliases /etc/aliases
keepbcc off
auth on
user apikey
password SENDGRID_API_KEY
tls on
tls_certcheck off
```

1. Command: echo -e "test" | msmtp --debug -t -i abc@test.com
   throwing below error, even if from header is set.

```
--> MAIL FROM:<xyz@domain.com>
--> RCPT TO:<abc@domain.com>
--> DATA
<-- 250 Sender address accepted
<-- 250 Recipient address accepted
<-- 354 Continue
--> test
--> .
<-- 550 MIME message is missing 'From' header
msmtp: the server did not accept the mail
msmtp: server message: 550 MIME message is missing 'From' header
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
```

able to send mail if header is set like below command.
2. Command: echo -e "test" "From:xyz@domain.com" | msmtp --debug -t -i abc@test.com

is there any way to enable send mail with first command itself?

msmtp configuration on one of self hosted bitrix instance